# react-native error when going over tutorial at react native site

Tags: react-native

I am a complete beginner, so please provide some explanation.

I am following react-native tutorial at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.19/docs/tutorial.html

I run command to init project, I just call it Movies instead of AwesomeProject as the tutorial explains.

Then I copied the complete code from the bottom of the tutorial into my index.ios.js, save the project and refreshed emulator and I get this error

```
error: bundling failed: "TransformError:
/Users/dinob/reactnativework/Movies/index.ios.js: 
Unexpected token ) (While processing preset:
\"/Users/dinob/reactnativework/Movies/node_modules/
babel-preset-react-native/index.js\")"
```

React-native-cli: 2.0.1
React-native: 0.47.1
React: 16.0.0-beta.2

[image]

Comment: Is it working if you don't use code from the tutorial?

Comment: hmmm, it does not, I am getting the same error ???!!!???  But another little tutorial I covered last ween is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can see is, the tutorial you're following is for `RN 0.19` while the newest stable version is 0.47. All the examples codes inside those use the older ES5 syntax and the not newer class based syntax that came in `ES6/ES2015`

Firstly, please make sure you're following the newest tutorial version and its code. You can do that from here.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html 
The error which I can see there is related to a babel transform and could possibly be attributed to newer version of React Native plus a newer version of React running older code. So you should probably start with a newer tutorial and take it from there. 
Also, the use of `react-native-cli` is now depreciated. You should use `create-react-native-app` to start a new project. It's all in the docs.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, as a complete beginner, that is exactly the kind of answer I needed.  The only problem is that the new tutorial is not covering at all what the old tutorial was and I needed the material in old tutorial.  Thank you so much!

Comment: I think 0.19 is a very low version to venture into, consider bumping into a more newer version if you want something older.
And you're welcome! I'm glad to have helped.

Comment: I did not even realize it is old since I literally started couple of weeks ago learning about RN whenever I can.  I was bit confused by some syntax in that tutorial but that is all.  Thanks again!

Comment: Pleasure to have helped mate!

Comment: My personal preference is WebStorm. That's an IDE and not just an editor. If you want something more light weight Atom is the way to go with proper RN plugins. Don't even go near Deco! It' s horrendous.

Comment: Thanks, I'm complete beginner and I tried so far athom and visual studio code.  Never heard for webstorm.  What does it offer that others don't?  Tx

Comment: For a start, it tells you if there's any error inside your code without the need for linters. It does code hinting and auto complete. There's plenty of other stuff too. It's probably a good idea to check https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/. There's a free month trial for one month.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed again.  Much appreciated

Comment: Any good resources you would recommend me for learning react native?

Comment: unfortunatelly WebStorm is not free, it is trial :(

Comment: Yes, it's not free I'm afraid. :)

Comment: Yes of course. There is one free resource. http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/

The other is a paid course on Udemy. 
https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-react-native-and-redux-course/