# React Native: app crash once started in AVD

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, react-native

This is the first time I use React Native. I have done the necessary preparation stated in the **Getting Started**.

- I created an app "test1"
- I opened the AVD in Android Studio.
- I ran >react-native run-android in the cmd.
- After some while, it said "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" in the cmd.

However, in the AVD, it displayed

> The development server returned response over code:500
>   in a red screen as shown below.

[image: android emulator screen]

Kindly tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Can you please add the error log as text instead of image?

Comment: Refer to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45779416/react-native-error-when-going-over-tutorial-at-react-native-site?noredirect=1#comment78516836_45779416